# How to show/hide component in parent component via a button in a child component when using a map of buttons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

A bit of a mouthful question...

I've looked over dozen of similar questions, but they either have to do with components in the same file, or with singular buttons.

**Desired Effect:**
I'm trying to display repository commits once a user clicks on a card of a specific repo. The commits are hidden until they press a button. If the user clicks the button when the commits are showing, it should hide the commits. Continuous clicking of a repo card should show/hide/show/hide/etc. the appropriate commit cards.

```
function Home() {
    const title = "Projects"
    const message = "Projects fetched from Github using their GQL API."
    const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false)
    const [repoInfo, setRepoInfo] = useState({ name: "Website", owner: "FernandoH-G" })

    return (
        <Container>
            <Jumbo title={title} message={message} />
            <CardDeck>
                <RepoCards clicked={clicked} setClicked={setClicked} setRepoInfo={setRepoInfo} />
            </CardDeck>
            <br/>
            <CardDeck>
                {clicked && <CommitCards repoInfo={repoInfo} />}
            </CardDeck>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

```
function RepoCards(props) {
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_PINNED_REPOS);
    const [radioValue, setRadioValue] = useState("");

    if (loading) return (
        <Loading
            message="Fetching pinned repositories..."
            color="secondary" />
    )
    if (error) return (
        <Loading
            message="Error fetching pinned repositories."
            color="danger" />
    )
    const pinEdges = data.user.pinnedItems.edges

    return (
        pinEdges.map((pin, idx) => (
            <Card
                key={pin.node.name}
                className="text-center"
                border="light">
                <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Header as="h5"> {pin.node.name}</Card.Header>
                    <Card.Link href={pin.node.url}>
                        <Card.Img variant="top" src={chooseIMG(pin.node.name)} />
                    </Card.Link>
                    <Card.Text> {pin.node.description}</Card.Text>
                </Card.Body>
                <ButtonGroup toggle>
                    <ToggleButton
                        key={pin.node.name}
                        type="radio"
                        variant="outline-secondary"
                        name="Button Radio"
                        value={pin.node.name}
                        checked={radioValue === pin.node.name}
                        onChange={(e) => setRadioValue(e.currentTarget.value)}
                        onClick={() => {
                            console.log(`${idx} card clicked. click value: ${props.clicked}`)
                            props.setRepoInfo(
                                {
                                    name: pin.node.name,
                                    owner: pin.node.owner.login
                                })
                            props.setClicked(!clicked) // This should work,right?

                            // if (radioValue === pin.node.name) {
                            //  // props.setClicked(prevVal => !prevVal)
                            //  props.setClicked(false)
                            // } else {props.setClicked(true)}
                        }}>
                        Last Update:{' '}
                        {parseDate(pin.node.pushedAt)}
                    </ToggleButton>
                </ButtonGroup>
            </Card>
        ))
    )
}
```

I'm including the CommitCards component code even though I don't think it's necessary.

```
const CommitCards = (props) => {
    const name = props.repoInfo.name
    const owner = props.repoInfo.owner
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_REPO_COMMITS, {
        variables: { name, owner },
    });
    if (loading) return (
        <Loading message={`Fetching ${name} commits...`} color="secondary" />
    );
    if (error) return (
        <Loading message={`Error fetching ${name} commits.`} color="danger" />
    );

    const commits = data.repository.defaultBranchRef.target.history.edges
    return commits.map(com => (
        <Card
            key={com.node.url}
            bg={"dark"}
            style={{ color: "white" }}
            border="info">
            <Card.Body>
                <Card.Link href={com.node.url}>
                    Commit Date:{'\n'}
                    {parseDate(com.node.committedDate)}
                </Card.Link>
                <Card.Text>
                    {parseText(com.node.message)}
                </Card.Text>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
    ))
}
```

After looking at the console, and recording the state of clicked, it may be a rendering issue. I say this because it seems to be rendering everything twice, thus messing with the value of clicked.

I don't know. I've been on this for a few days now. Below is a screenshot of the consoles output after I click each button. Commits fail to even show; not close to having the effect I desire.

[image: console output]

## Huge development

Following the suggestion of @deckele, I was working on a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-butterfly-myxo1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) when I noticed that my initial code posted...actually works, sorta. I can definitely optimize the posted code. I wasn't able to get react-bootstrap to work in code sandbox, but that turned out for the better.

It turns out that a `<ToggleButton>` reads clicking the label, the text portion, as a click on the console, twice. However, you have to hit the *very small* actual input area. You can check out the label registering as a click in the code sandbox.
[image: input_covered]
Unfortunately, the input area is covered by the label, which is essentially the whole button.

Since this question took a turn, I will be closing up this one, and probably opening up a new react-bootstrap one.

Comment: Can you please provide a CodeSandbox of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably more ways to get this working.

I think you can get away without using `clicked` state in `Home` - if I'm not missing something I'm not sure why you would need it

You could:

#### 1. In `Home`

- keep only `repoInfo` and get rid of `clicked`
- initiate `repoInfo` with `null` or the value you want to be loaded on mount
- pass `repoInfo` and `setRepoInfo` down to `RepoCards`
- change the `clicked` check with `reportInfo`

```js
function Home() {
  const title = 'Projects';
  const message = 'Projects fetched from Github using their GQL API.';
  const [repoInfo, setRepoInfo] = useState({
    name: 'Website',
    owner: 'FernandoH-G',
  }); // if you initiate repoInfo with `null` you won't have a repo selected in mount

  return (
    <Container>
      <Jumbo title={title} message={message} />
      <CardDeck>
        <RepoCards
          setRepoInfo={setRepoInfo}
          reportInfo={repoInfo}
        />
      </CardDeck>
      <br />
      <CardDeck>{repoInfo && <CommitCards repoInfo={repoInfo} />}</CardDeck>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

#### 2. In `RepoCards`

- get rid of `radioValue` - you won't use it; you can determine the `checked` value using `repoInfo`
- remove `onClick` from `ToggleButton` and use just `onChange` changed to something like

```js
<ToggleButton
  key={pin.node.name}
  type="radio"
  variant="outline-secondary"
  name="Button Radio"
  value={pin.node.name}
  checked={props.reportInfo && props.reportInfo.name === pin.node.name}
  onChange={() => {
    const newReportInfo =
      props.reportInfo && props.reportInfo.name === pin.node.name
        ? null
        : {
            name: pin.node.name,
            owner: pin.node.owner.login,
          };
    props.setRepoInfo(newReportInfo);
  }}
>
  Last Update: {parseDate(pin.node.pushedAt)}
</ToggleButton>;
```

Comment: Hello. clicked served a similar purpose as repoInfo in Home. Unfortunately, your suggestions don't seem to have the effect I'm looking for. Continuous clicking of a repo button does not show/hide/show/etc the commit cards. Clicking it once does not even hide the commit cards once they are displayed. I have edited my question to emphasize the effect I desire.

Comment: I do notice that your suggestions seems to solve the multi render issues. Would you be able to explain why that is the case? Does onClick simply lead to multiple renders when it comes to map components?

Comment: My first guess was you got multiple renders because you have 2 actions on `ToggleButton`. Clicking the button calls both `onChange` and `onClick`: `onChange` updates the state of the component and `onClick` triggers a change of  props - by changing a value in the parent. What I don't understand is why it looks like you actually got `onClick` called on re-render. 
Is `ToggleButton` a component from a library or something you build? Is it possible it uses an `effect` and calls `onClick` on some props changes?

Comment: _Continuous clicking of a repo button does not show/hide/show/etc the commit cards._: I edited the `onChange` function in `RepoCards`. This should do the trick - not sure what event `ToggleButton` is emitting so I used what we know from props

Comment: `ToggleButton` is from the [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/buttons/#toggle-button-props) library.

Comment: It still doesn't work. When I print out some console.logs, after `pin.reportInfo` is not null, clicking the same button does not trigger an `onChange` event.  Therefore, the `props.reportInfo && props.reportInfo.name === pin.node.name` condition is never true.

Comment: I tried renaming it from `onChange` to `onClick` to see if it caused an event to trigger, and it did, but twice. It seems `onClick` causes 2 renders that mess with the values...

Comment: I'll accept this question since I appreciate the effort! However, the actual issue was totally unrelated to the code.